# Using Qt5 in a library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, qt5

I have a library that integrates some GTK functionnalities, and I decided to switch to Qt.
So I created a test cmake file to try to integrate Qt5 but it does not work because when I load the libary dynamically using an executable I get "undefined symbols".

```
undefined symbol: _ZN8UIWindow16staticMetaObjectE
```

I googled a lot, and it does not seems to be that simple si any kind of help, or comments would be much appreciated.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/athanase/5524646) are the relevant files I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. Since I use different folders for the header and the source files, I have to manually specify where is the file containing the qt code.

`QT5_WRAP_CPP( MOCS_HDRS ${INCLUDE_DIR}/UIWindow.h )`

Comment: Is this a limitation of automoc?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the MOC file for your UIWindow class was not generated or built correctly.  Qt expects certain meta-information for the class generated by MOC (MetaObject Compiler, IIRC).
Your CMake script turns on automoc which usually works, so I suggest you take a look at the output of CMake to see if it is running that step for your class or not.

Comment: Ok. I checked in the build folder and I have a file libtest_automoc.cpp (in addition the expected other files: libtest.so, etc). But the file is almost empty so there might be something wrong with the generation of the mocs. `/* This file is autogenerated, do not edit*/
enum some_compilers { need_more_than_nothing };`

Comment: @Athanase - I would expect a moc_UIWindow.cpp file around in your build location too - and that file should not be empty but full of generated code.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea why... I looked a this [post](http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5./) and this [example](https://bitbucket.org/klaim/aos_qt5/src/593c195c4c6889f6968d68fca018ef425783a063/tools/aosdesigner/CMakeLists.txt?at=wip_qt5) but it did not help me.

Comment: The commented-out line (78 I think it was) in your CMake script calls moc manually, try enabling that and checking the difference.

Comment: I commented this line because it does not change anything when I search for .moc files. Nothing is generated :(

Comment: Take a look at your CMake log, see what CMake and the build system are actually doing.

Comment: Did not find anything useful [here](https://gist.github.com/athanase/5524646#file-cmakeoutput-log)

Comment: But in the [MakeFile](https://gist.github.com/athanase/5524646#file-makefile) it seems that the class UIWindow is built with `libtest` but should be build within `libtest_automoc`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29486/discussion-between-madkeithv-and-athanase)